# Dynamically creating a CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, dynamic, checkboxlist

I am trying to create a dynamic menu with a title and group of checkboxes. So the output would be something like this: (pseudocode-ly)

**Title 1**

-checkbox1 -checkbox2 -checkbox3

**Title 2**

-checkbox1 -checkbox2 -checkbox3

I can get the Title back just fine, but my checkboxes are not. (See below)

**Care**

System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList

**Corporate & Enterprise Solutions**

System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList

I realize I am returning a DataSet, I just don't know how to handle it.

```
BusinessUnit bu = new BusinessUnit();    
DataSet businessNames = bu.ListBusinessUnitNames();    
ArrayList buNames = new ArrayList();

if (businessNames.Tables.Count > 0 && businessNames.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in businessNames.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                buNames.Add(row["BSUN_NAME"].ToString());
            }                
        }
        int counter = 1;
        foreach (string name in buNames)
        {
            Label lblName = new Label();
            lblName.ID = "unitName_" + counter;
            lblName.Text = name;

            CheckBoxList chkBoxes = new CheckBoxList();
            chkBoxes.ID = name + "Programs_" + counter;

            foreach (string item in buNames)
            {
                DataSet buPrograms = bu.ListBusinessUnitPrograms(item);
                foreach (DataRow row in buPrograms.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    chkBoxes.DataTextField = row[0].ToString();
                    chkBoxes.Text = chkBoxes.DataTextField;
                }
            }

            programs.InnerHtml += lblName.Text + chkBoxes;
            counter++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the mechanics for doing it in code:

```
ListItem LI1 = new ListItem("aaa");
ListItem LI2 = new ListItem("bbb");

LI1.Selected = true;
LI2.Selected = false;

chkBoxes.Items.Add(LI1);
chkBoxes.Items.Add(LI2);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're using WebForms [aspx])

In your code example, the statement `programs.InnerHtml += lblName.Text + chkBoxes;` is appending the value of the default .ToString() implementation of the chkBoxes object.  To actually add the checkboxes to the page, you will need some sort of container control (such as a Placeholder) on the page, and append your dynamically created control to the container's Controls collection via `phPlaceholder.Controls.Add(chkBoxes)`